It shows ' ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' ' when I ran a python .exe file on command prompt in win10
I wrote a python program on PyCharm, the code is shown in the picture 1. Then I created a .exe file for this program on PyCharm. I ran this .exe file on command prompt, it showed that ' ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' '. This problem is shown in the picture 2. How can I solve this problem? Thank you.
picture 1
picture 2

Please provide the code you tried, not pictures of code.

Can you tell me your email, I can send the code to your email. Thank you.
